# Weird error with import file in python

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I have a flask setup with few import files in it.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template,request,redirect, url_for,json,jsonify
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import Dmyabc as dmyab
```

`import Dmyabc as dmyab` was working fine before and I was calling my functions from it using:

```
dmyab.run1()
dmyab.total()
```

But suddenly it stopped working and started giving out an error as

> Object doesn't have attribute run1 or total

Can anybody tell me what's has exactly happend so that I can avoid it in future.

For now I am using the same file as:

```
from Dmyabc import run1, total
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have a `dmyab` object created or after `import Dmyab as dmyab` that shadows the `Dmyab` module imported as `dmyab`.
You can check that by doing something like `print type(dmyab)`, you should get something else than a module...
Your workaround works because you directly import functions from the module; but it could work the same probably if you do something like this:

```
import Dmyab as other_dmyab
[...]
other_dmyab.run1()
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks @mgguijarr, Looks like I was using keywork dmyab at lot many places, but when I changed and imported using **other_dmyab** It started working fine. Right now didn't get much time to find out what is overlapping it but I am sure I will find out. Thanks again